# Image optimization weird question

Tags: image, optimization

I have an image and was trying to optimize it as a png. I see that it doesnt have many colors but no matter what I try I cant get it smaller.

Any ideas what in particular makes this file so large

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2982102/AG/Portal/1.0/css/light/images/paper_01.png

I tried smushit.com as well as some local png compression tools and I am stumped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This image has quite a busy texture to it, even though the number of colors is small; the original size is legitimate. If you reduce the number of colors even further, you can make it tiny but you will lose some detail; with an image this subtle, the detail loss may be acceptable. Using Paint Shop Pro I am able to reduce to 16 colors with the Octree method and get it down to 214 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect most of the file space is used to store a color palette that is bigger than it needs to be.

Switching the image to RGB in The GIMP brings it down to 966 bytes.

And switching to a smaller color palette makes it even smaller. Try this:

- load the picture in The GIMP
- switch mode to RGB
- switch mode back to indexed, and select "use 1-bit palette"
- save

I've got it down to 164 with the above method.